# Architecture components: Observer keep observing even after removing it on onDestroy

Tags: android, android-room, android-handler, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm developing an app where I need to do a network call every 30 seconds, and delete the previous data and insert the new one. And every time the new data is inserted I'm showing it in the RecyclerView. I'm using Handler to give a network call and LiveData for observing data changes. Everything just works fine, just Live data observer triggers multiple time, so the data is getting deleted and inserted multiple times in result to refresh the RecyclerView frequently causing it to flash multiple times every 30 seconds.

So below is the code what I've tried:

In my Fragment I do this:

```
private LiveData<List<RestaurantTablesModel>> mData;
private Observer<List<RestaurantTablesModel>> mObserver;
private TablesViewModel mViewModel;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tables, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);

    TablesViewModelFactory factory = InjectorUtils.provideTablesFactory(getActivity());
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(TablesViewModel.class);

    setUpUserRecyclerView();

    return mView;

}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {

  mData = mViewModel.getTablesData(mLocationID);

    mObserver = tablesModels -> {
        if (tablesModels != null) {
            mTablesRecyclerAdapter.addTables(tablesModels);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setUpUserRecyclerView: tablesModels");
        }
    };

  mData.observe(this, mObserver);
}
```

Removing the observer onDestroy:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   mData.removeObserver(mObserver);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Following is my method in ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<TablesModel>> getTablesData(int mLocationID){
    return mRepository.getTablesData(mLocationID);
}
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<List<TablesModel>> getTablesData(int mLocationID){

    LiveData<TablesModel[]> mTablesData = mDataSource.getTablesData();

    mTablesData.observeForever(tablesModels -> {
        mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {

            //Completed: delete old table data if there are conflicts.

            if (tablesModels != null) {
                mDatabaseDao.deleteTables();

                mDatabaseDao.insertTablesData(tablesModels);
            }else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Nothing: ");
            }
        });
        Log.e("Handlers", "repository getTablesData");
    });

    return mDatabaseDao.getTablesData(mLocationID);
}
```

DataSource:

```
private MutableLiveData<RestaurantTablesModel[]> mDownloadedTablesModel;

public LiveData<RestaurantTablesModel[]> getTablesData() {
    Log.e("Handlers", "getTablesData");
    fetchTablesData();
    return mDownloadedTablesModel;
}

public void fetchTablesData() {

    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
        NetworkUtils.NetworkInterface mInterface = this;

        handler = new Handler();

        runnableCode = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something here on the main thread
                Log.e("Handlers", "Called on network thread");

                URL getTablesURL = NetworkUtils.getAllTableUrl(mContext);

                NetworkUtils.getResponseFromAPI(mContext, getTablesURL, mInterface);

                // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 30 seconds
                // 'this' is referencing the Runnable object
                handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
            }
        };

        handler.post(runnableCode);

    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fetchTablesData: No network!");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when my fragment is destroyed and recreated the Observer gets triggered multiple times, here are the logs:

```
09-05 10:28:29.853 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
09-05 10:28:30.039 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
09-05 10:28:30.607 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
09-05 10:28:30.657 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
09-05 10:28:30.669 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
09-05 10:28:30.704 3666-3666/? E/TablesFragment: setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels
```

And it triggers more times than before, every time fragment is recreated, I think it the observer is getting called on a recreation of the fragment and the previous instance of the observer is still in a play.

But if I'm removing the observer in OnDestroy, why should it be happening?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I changed my code to check if the LiveData and Observer are null, and then only initialize it. But it doesn't help, it is still getting called multiple times.

```
if (mTablesData == null){
        mData = mViewModel.getTablesData(mLocationID);

        if (mObserver == null){
            mObserver = tablesModels -> {
                if (tablesModels != null) {
                    mTablesRecyclerAdapter.addTables(tablesModels);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setUpUserRecyclerView: tablesModels");
                }
            };

            mData.observe(this, mObserver);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Tried this also, but didn't work as well:

```
   mTablesData = mViewModel.getTablesData(mLocationID);

    mObserver = tablesModels -> {
        if (tablesModels != null) {
            mTablesRecyclerAdapter.addTables(tablesModels);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setUpRecyclerView: tablesModels");
        }
    };

    if (!mTablesData.hasObservers()) {
        mTablesData.observe(this, mObserver);
    }
```

Comment: Is the `onDestroy` method even called? Did you tried to set a breakpoint to see if the observer is really removed?

Comment: I just put LOG in onDestroy, and yes it is getting called

Comment: As @pskink mentionend, maybe your method is called multiple times. Check if mData & mObserver is null before you are creating these variabels, to prevent recreation. But this method should be called only once.

Comment: Okay, let me try this..

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work, see my edit and tell me if I'm still doing something wrong

Comment: No no, I'm getting it multiple time than usual when I'm recreating the fragment after destroying it

Comment: I don't know if it survives fragments death or not, but when I close the app and starts the log is printed 2-3 times, but if I go back to previous activity and comes back to the same activity which is hosting my fragment, the log is printed 3-4 times and the more I go back and forth the no of logs are getting increased

Comment: Please try adding an observer only if no observers are already added: 
`if (!mData.hasObservers()) {
            mData.observe(this, mObserver);
        }`

Comment: @DeividasStrioga I just tried it, I thought It'd work, but it didn't, Logs are still getting printed multiple times, My RecyclerView is still flashing

Comment: Also try doing the same in your repo: `mTablesData.observeForever(tablesModels -> {...`. It looks like a root cause, the use of `mTablesData.observeForever` is unadvisable.

Comment: You don't need `mData.removeObserver(mObserver);` on destroy as that is the function of live data, they unsubscribe automatically. BTW, how do you set the downloaded data to mDownloadedTablesModel?

Comment: I think I solved it, I checked if the mTablesData hasObservers, in the repository and it worked, it's not getting called multiple times now

Comment: Thank you very much @DeividasStrioga, I was trying to solved it for hours

Comment: First I'm calling NetworkUtils.getResponseFromAPI and upon getting response I'm posting the value to mDownloadedTablesModel using interface by
`mDownloadedTablesModel.postValue(tablesModel)`

Comment: If using observeForever is unadvisable then what should i be using inside repo? I can't use observe as I don't have lifeCycleOwner in the repo, right?

Comment: Or should i pass on instance of the LifeCycleOwner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what we learned from experiments in the comments, you needed to check if `mTablesData` is already being observed before observing it, and observe only if it is not being observed, like

`if (!mTablesData.hasObservers()) {
mTablesData.observeForever(tablesModels -> {
...`

Answer (score 1):

First, If I understand correct you use `RecyclerView` and every fragment in that `RecyclerView` called `setUpUserRecyclerView();` in its `onCreate()` method. So, if you have 3 Fragments, you will have 3 Observers. If you want all of them to use the `ViewModel` of the `Activity` you have to point the parent Activity here -> `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), factory)`

Second, Why do you use `observeForever` in your Repository? Can you use just `observe`?

And last if you want to run this request in every 30 seconds, why don't you use `PeriodicWorkRequest` of `WorkManager` -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#java

Hope I help somehow :)

Comment: No, I have only one fragment that does have a `RecyclerView`. 
Anyway, I solved it, using Deividas Strioga's help.
But thanks for telling me about `PeriodicWorkRequest` I'd definitely check that out

Comment: Cool, happy to help at least with one thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need wrap the mObserver in a CompositeDisposable.

```
CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

disposable.add(mObserver);

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   mData.removeObserver(mObserver);
   disposable.clear();
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is it related to RxJAVA? Cause I'm not using it

Comment: Sorry I thought the observer was a rxjava observer